# My Neo4j Brower doesn't show "text" and and "table" views any more

Tags: neo4j

Normally, a search query result shows "graph", "table", "code" views in the browser. But now I can only see the graph, no table or text or code views.

What might cause this?

Comment: Can you show a query that causes this behavior?

Comment: I tried all different queries. The basic one doesn't work either "MATCH (n1)-[r]->(n2) RETURN r, n1, n2 LIMIT 25". It only displays the graph. The 'table' and 'text' are blank when I click.

Comment: Which navigator are you using ? Is there some errors in the JS console ? Have you try to clear the navigator cache (and coockies + localstorage) ?